# Change from const to property and static context (C#)

Tags: c#, static, properties

I had a public class like that:

```
public class ClassN
{
    public const int SomeInt = 16;
    ...
}
```

This was called from somewhere else using

```
int myInt = ClassN.SomeInt
```

Now I have to change the 16 to something more dynamic and that looks like this:

```
public int SomeInt
{
    get
    {
         //this method is not static and cant be changed to static 
         return GetIntDynamically();    
    }
}
```

Of course the call is not working anymore, because of static context. I cant create a new instance of ClassN ... what another option that does not violate coding rules?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a new instance of ClassN? If you can explain the reasoning behind this statement we may be able to suggest something.

Comment: I think you meant `public static int SomeInt`? Otherwise there’s no problem with the non-static method call.

Comment: @David: I’m referring to the property, not the const field.

Comment: @Timwi. Ah, OK, misunderstood. In that case, please see the comment inside the getter's body...

Comment: @Timwi: He sure didn't mean that, because that's what this question is all about...

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: You can't create an object of ClassN but you need yo use `this` which requires an object.

Answer (score 0):

If `GetIntDynamically` is not static and can't be made static, you have no other option as to create an instance of `ClassN`.

Comment: The problem is, in that method I use "this", which is not allowed in static context.

Comment: The problem is not with the use of `this` per se, but that using `this` means that you are using other instance members of the class in that method. I think David is right in his comment: Please explain, why you can't create an instance of ClassN.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create a new instance of `ClassN`, but your method is relying on some instance state by using the `this` keyword, then you are needing to call the method on a particular known instance of `ClassN`. If it's the only such, then you could perhaps consider implementing a singleton pattern. If it's not the only such instance, then you will need to make a reference to the right instance available to your calling code. So as I said in my comment, we need to understand more about your situation to answer this fully. However, the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern may be what you are after...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class ClassN 
{
    public static int SomeInt = 16;     
    ...
}
```